# Life cycle of a blob

Tags: network, danksharding, eip-4844

I am trying to understand the life cycle of a blob (in the context of proto danksharding/danksharding). Basically from the point it is assembled by a source(like a L2 node) to the time it is eventually purged by a L1 node.

In particular: how it is gossiped, which nodes download it, do the downloaders fetch the full blob or parts of the blob.

I read through the EIPs and other docs, I could not get a full picture. It would be great if someone could outline the steps in the lifecycle if possible. Or point me to some relevant links

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If no two owns download for the blob then he should do all the utility he is complete do not share the download with node one